# How to generate any protobuf Enum as String with only one TypeMapper?

Tags: scala, scalapb

For instance, I have some enums in my proto schema:

```
enum E1 {
     UNKNOWN = 0;
     OPTION_1 = 1;
     OPTION_2 = 2;
     OPTION_3 = 3;
}

enum E2 {
     UNKNOWN = 0;
     ANOTHER_OPTION_1 = 1;
     ANOTHER_OPTION_2 = 2;
     ANOTHER_OPTION_3 = 3;
}

message M {
    E1 my_enum_1 = 1;
    E2 my_enum_2 = 2;
}
```

I can generate scala classes with strings instead of enums by providing `scalaPB` `TypeMapper`s:

```
TypeMapper(_.name)(E1.fromName(_).get)
TypeMapper(_.name)(E2.fromName(_).get)
```

But I don't want to copypaste same TypeMappers for any single Enum

Is there any way to make only one TypeMapper for all enums with `scalaPB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.

If you want to make ScalaPB use String for all enums within a package, you can add [package-scoped options](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/customizations/#package-scoped-options) file to tell ScalaPB to set the scala-type for each enum to a `String` using [field transformations](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/transformations):

```proto
// options.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

import "scalapb/scalapb.proto";

option (scalapb.options) = {
  scope: PACKAGE,
  field_transformations : [
    {
      when : {
        type: TYPE_ENUM
      }
      set : {[scalapb.field] {type : 'String'}}
    }
}
```

The next step will be to define a typemapper for all enums. Borrowing from Ivan's answer, this could be defined as follows:

```scala
implicit def enumMapper[E <: GeneratedEnum](implicit ec: GeneratedEnumCompanion[E]) =
  TypeMapper[E, String](_.name)(ec.fromName(_).get)
```

If the above code is added to a package object in the same package as the generated code, *or* imported using the `import` option in ScalaPB, the typemapper will be found in implicit search.

Answer (score 1):

You can't completely avoid defining `TypeMapper` for each `enum` type you have. But you could create a helper method to create `TypeMapper` instances.

For example

```scala
import scalapb.GeneratedEnum
import scalapb.GeneratedEnumCompanion
import scalapb.TypeMapper

def enumMapper[E <: GeneratedEnum: GeneratedEnumCompanion] = {
  TypeMapper[E, String](_.name)(implicitly[GeneratedEnumCompanion[E]].fromName(_).get)
}
```

---UPDATE---

Following on @thesamet comment, if you add `implicit` to the method above and have it available in your implicit context, it will work.

This can be tested with following code that compiles

```scala
implicit def enumMapper...

val Enum1Mapper = implicitly[TypeMapper[E1]]
```

Comment: If the typemapper is placed in a package object in the same package the code is generated, or is imported through the scalapb `import` option, then the generic mapper above would be found.

Comment: yes, you're correct. I missed the `implicit` key for this to work